# Intellij 13.1 doesn't show Android File Templates

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, intellij-13

I noticed my intellij ide doesn't show the **File Templates** related to Android when I `Right click > New`. There is only an **Image Assets** which makes a launcher icon for the app. 
There should be other templates such as blank activity/fragment/service etc.

[image]
I've tried restarting the IDE or creating a fresh project with no luck.

The file templates do exist in the installation folder:
[image]
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: I have the same issue. Please tell me if you find a solution. I also reported the problem to JetBrains in case you are interested.
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-123624

Comment: @GregorKoukkoullis Great! I will let you know if I find a fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug and has been fixed in the latest update.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click in the Java package where you would like the source files to go. It should give you more relevant options.